# get scope value from core_config_data

Tags: core, scope, core-config-data

I need to get the 'scope' value from core_config_data table of the current scope that has been selected by the user in the admin-panel. I've tried several methods posted in this site without success, for example:

```
Mage::app()->getWebsite()->getConfig('.../.../...')  Returns bool(false) 

Mage_Core_Model_Website::getConfig() Returns the same...
```

I've also tried to get some random 'scope_id' and then get its 'scope' value, but this doesn't work since the same 'scope_id' value can be used for different 'scope' values and can't get the current scope value that i need.

Is there a way i can get the 'scope' value of the current scope selected by the user?.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Solved by getting the current scope value with this:

```
$scope = Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/config_data')->getScope();
```

Comment: put full answer